# Why won't regex pass a parameter in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-url

```
$route['[0-9A-Za-z]'] = "editor/index/$1";
```

When I look at my editor controller, in the index method, I don't get the paramter passed. It just says "$1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just `$route[ '(:any)' ] = "editor"`

Then just handle as necessary:

```
function index() {
    $id = $this->uri->segment( 3 ); // Or whatever segment you end up with.

    // Do something.
}
```